# What is an example of three numbers that do not make up a vector?

Tags: vectors, linear-algebra

In one of Feynman's lectures he mentions that:

> Of course it is generally not true that *any* three numbers form a
> vector
>
> In order for it to be a vector, not only must there be three numbers,
> but these must be associated with a coordinate system in such a way
> that if we turn the coordinate system, the three numbers “revolve” on
> each other, get “mixed up” in each other, by the precise laws we have
> already described.

A quick google about vectors and I see things like " a vector is an element of a vector space". Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) has a list of 8 axioms that must be satisfied to have a vector space. Reading through these axioms, I can't imagine any 3 numbers that when combined to form a vector, wouldn't satisfy these axioms. I'd love some help in understanding what Feynman is meaning here.

Comment: I can almost guarantee that you’ll end up with more confusions if you try to understand vectors the way Feynman suggests. Learning linear algebra proper, the way a mathematician would (vector spaces and all) will easily bypass many questions and misconceptions you may come up with/have now and in the future (if you want to learn higher level math and physics…GR, QM…), as I’ve seen repeatedly with the different students I’ve TAed. See for example my answer on MSE [What exactly is a "vector" in math (in terms of vector spaces)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4351469/568204) for more remarks.

Comment: @peek-a-boo The central issue is that the definition of vector in maths is much less restrictive than the physical definition of vector. And in this case it should be that the maths that should change—the name "Linear space" is a better fit. So, if you try to look in the maths texts to learn about vectors, it is very likely that the basic stuff would completely miss what Feynman is referring to, i.e. your advice is incredibly dangerous.

Comment: Three consecutive house numbers?

Comment: I suspect you may have fundamentally misunderstood Feynman's claim. He's not saying "there are some numbers (abstract integers) that don't make up a vector". He's saying "to be a vector those numbers have to be associated in some manner that allows them to interact" - you need numbers **and a description of what those numbers mean**.

So yes, any 3 numbers you can think of form a vector **if you interpret them as, say, spacial co-ordinates**.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I agree that the concept of vector Feynman is referring to here is a specialization of the math one, and indeed terminology is somewhat unfortunate, but everyone is guilty here (since math and physics people overload and abuse terminology). Anyway, let’s not make this a math vs Physics thing. My point is that for a student to appreciate the transformation-based definition of a concept (tensor or vector) requires so much more effort on the students’ part, in order to truly separate the idea of the geometric object being referred to from its components.

Comment: which sounds funny of course, since the transformation definition literally tells one to separate the two ideas, yet as we can clearly see based on the mirade of questions on PhySE, something isn’t clicking with students. On the other hand, with the vector space definition, the usual push back isn’t “what are you talking about”, it’s “why bother with abstraction”, and the latter is much easier to address. So, it is surprising that the way things are taught resembles essentially the way people learned/phrased them close to a century ago.

Comment: Yes, it would require more effort, but that is a generally applicable concept that pays for the effort over and over. One never shies away from putting that effort in, in maths education elsewhere, so why should the pedagogy suddenly turn away here? @peek-a-boo The thing is that, with physics, the motivation for the need for those properties can be very easily supplied, and so it is easy to get to good pedagogy on the matter. I do not see why the universal lack of education on the topic, hence all the questions on P.SE, should be taken as evidence that it should NOT be taught.

Comment: i wonder if Feynman is making a distinction between contravariant and covariant quantities?

Comment: My weight, your age and Pi.  Three numbers, but *not a vector*.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I didn’t mean to imply it should not be taught (hence in my first comment I said “bypass” rather than completely ignore), rather that it shouldn’t be the first thing to be taught. This description, more conceptually, also requires the notion the notion of a linear representation of a group on a vector space to properly pin down (and also has important global generalizations such as the concept of a $G$-structure). Given all this necessary extra data, it seems unreasonable/inefficient to be the first introduction (even if historically thing unfolded differently).

Comment: @peek-a-boo That I agree, but then I have to point out that nobody is claiming that people should teach vectors with the transformations as the first approach. Not least since students see vectors at as low as age 14 here, and this topic is purely varsity level. Ok, I cheat, I am teaching my students that early, but only as a teaser after they demonstrate understanding of the basic linear space ideas.

Comment: A woman's measurements does not a vector make.

Comment: TLDR: It's a vector if you _call_ it a vector and you _use_ it like a vector. Any ordered sequence of numbers potentially could be used like a vector. Um,... except,... If you're in the math department, then there's a lot of different things that you can call, "number." In order to make a vector out of them, the need to all be members of the same [algebraic field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)).

Answer (score 52):

If I click the "share" link under your question, I get the URL  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/768023/44126. If I click on your username, I get the URL  https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/295770/zinn.  There are three numbers in these two links:

1. the database index of your question, 768023
2. the database index of my user account, 44126
3. the database index of your user account, 295770

You could combine these numbers into a list, where the first number is the post ID, the second number is the user ID of the person who has requested a "share" link, and the third number is the user ID of the person who has made the question. But now you have to ask whether a process of "vector addition," which is a prerequisite to the axioms you list in the Wikipedia article, even makes any sense.  If you just use ordinary addition on the different "components" of the "vector," then the results of "adding up two posts" don't really mean anything.  In particular, the space of posts is not closed under addition: if we construct one of these "vectors" for somebody else's post, and add up the database IDs, we will almost certainly not get a "vector" that points to another Physics Stack Exchange post. The additive identity isn't a member of the vector space, because there isn't any post or user with database identifier zero. There is no additive inverse in the vector space, because there aren't any database identifiers with negative numbers.

Note the Wikipedia page you link to defines a *mathematical* vector space. When physicists talk about vectors, including in your Feynman quote, we are typically not talking about any possible abstract vector space, but specifically about vectors which can describe the locations of objects relative to one another in the world where we live. Those physical vectors are subject to additional transformation rules, which allow you to get from the three numbers you would choose as the coordinates of your vector to the three numbers which would be chosen by someone who is looking at the same objects from a different seat at your table. If this other observer is sitting across from you, or is suspended from the ceiling above you, their coordinates will be related to yours by a "rotation." It is the rotation properties which define physics vectors.

Comment: I find it quite dangerous and not scientifically based to maintain a difference between vectors in Physics and in Mathematics.

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 I agree. But in the mathematical sense, what physicists call spinors are also "vectors", though they differ from physicists' vectors in the way they transform under rotation. Perhaps giving another name to physicists' vectors would solve the problem? Or perhaps it'll become even more confusing...

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 Keeping the distinction between physics and mathematics is *essential*. The objects mathematics studies do not exist outside of human minds, but the objects that physics studies exist in nature. The disciplines are different: mathematics is constrained by consistency while physics is constrained by real phenomena. Mathematical objects like vectors are thus only useful to physics to the extent that they accurately model the phenomena in question. That requires *meaning*, not consistency. Indeed, we get to be sloppy about consistency, because nature rules.

Comment: @JohnDoty, that's an opinion not shared by all the physicists. Usually, after studying some more math, one discovers that sloppy usage of math is not necessary to do good Physics.

Comment: @GiorgioP There are tons of examples of non-Euclidean vector spaces in physics; they just don't show up in the first semester of an introductory course. At the end of an intro course many students learn about Minkowski four-vectors, which are closed under both rotations *and* boosts. Anyone who has referred to a continuous three-dimensional probability density as an "eigenvector" has had a discussion about abstract vector spaces. I would compare the situation to a word like "meme," which has a technical meaning for which "picture with words on it" is merely a common example.

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 There are other views of the matter. Mathematics by itself is a study of language and has as such no bearing on science at all. It is a conversational topic, like horticulture. It is precisely the utility it has in describing objective measurements of "reality" that lends it credibility.

Comment: Once I asked a question on Math SE about the difference between a physical and mathematical vector space: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/789956/1190 It might have some useful info.

Comment: "There are tons of examples of non-Euclidean vector spaces in physics" - May I ask what this has to do with Giorgio's comment?

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 So, you have a quantum theory of gravity consistent with the Standard Model? Or, when analyzing a falling object, do you use theory that's empirically verified, but not rigorously consistent?

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 Unfortunately, Jack Schwartz's excellent essay "The Pernicious Influence of Mathematics on Science" doesn't seem to be accessible on line, but you should see if you can find a copy.

Comment: @JohnDoty I do not understand your point of view. The lack of a quantum theory of gravity consistent with the Standard Model is a problem of Physics, not of Math.

Comment: The distinction between vectors in mathematics and physics is a pragmatic one. Yes, to mathematicians any three (or two, or whatever) numbers can form a vector. A physicist additionally simply _demands_ the vector to be a useful sensible entity for physics purposes, or they are just not interested.

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 As I said, we get to be sloppy about consistency, because nature rules. We cannot use consistent mathematics to model a falling object, because we don't have consistent physics. Still, we can very successfully model falling objects using math that is sloppy and inconsistent by mathematical standards. We don't need mathematical consistency: we need models that match reality.

Comment: @DavidZ Nice to see your name again, old friend. Hope all is well.

Comment: @EuroMicelli, it is false that any three (or two, or whatever) numbers can form a vector to mathematicians. They form a vector only after defining the multiplication by a scalar and the sum of those three numbers. Once one understands this essential point,  the usefulness of not separating vectors, according to mathematicians or physicists, should become clear.

Comment: @Stian Your description of math as a study of language is only true for uselessly broad definitions of language.  Mathematics can be viewed as the study of *information* and *patterns*, which is distinct from the language of Mathematics.  The formal symbol manipulation of Mathematics is only part of Mathematics, and mistaking that map (the language of mathematics) for the territory is an error.  The patterns Mathematics study is include the patterns of "vector space", "numbers", "geometry", "cardinality" and the like; these are very abstract patterns!

Comment: @JohnDoty Can you explain what you mean by 'We cannot use consistent mathematics to model a falling object'. I can think of half a dozen ways to model falling objects depending on context and which effects you want to include or simplify away. All of them use consistent maths are consistent within themselves. Their predictions are more or less accurate depending on context. I can't think of a single model that doesn't use consistent math.

Comment: In theoretical physics, when physicists talk about vectors and scalars, they are referring to how the object behaves under transformations.  For example, a scalar field $\phi_a(x)$ transform as $\phi_a (\Lambda x)$ under a Lorentz transformation, it's nothing to do with the number of components etc.  Also it's worth pointing out that Feynman's approach and way of viewing things were considered to be rather unrigorous (or eccentric) even from the physics point of view and he was ultimately justified by the fact that the calculations always worked.

Comment: @quqrangue I should have said *physically* consistent mathematics. Results based on approximations depend on the chosen approximation, and are also not consistent with the physical laws chosen as the basis of the approximation. Those laws are generally themselves approximations. This is part of Schwartz's point in his essay. Mathematically, the whole ediface is unstable, but it works because our foundations aren't axioms but experiments.

Comment: Your "database indexes" example is really just showing that database identifiers have no sensible arithmetic defined on them, therefore neither do tuples of them. As nearly every other answer points out, the true issue is whether vector addition and scalar multiplication are defined. It has *nothing* to do with describing the locations of objects in 3D space -- that's far too narrow, even for Newtonian physics! No reason to ever draw a thick line between math and physics.

Answer (score 23):

Temperature, density, and water vapor concentration at one point in the atmosphere are three numbers. However, any triple of such values is unaffected by a change in the spatial reference frame. More or less, this is the idea behind Feynman's words.

However, Feynman's argument was not quite accurate from a mathematical point of view. He made a good point, stressing that a triple of numbers does not necessarily represent a vector, but he made a wrong example and missed the real problem.

Let me show a counterexample where the weakness of Feynman's argument can be easily seen, showing at the same time why not every triple of number can be interpreted as the set of components of a $3D$ vector.

Let's associate an arrow to a rotation in the space, such that the arrow orientation encodes the axis of rotation and the rotation direction, the arrow length is the size of the rotation angle.

Of course, we can associate three components to such arrows, and clearly, any change of the cartesian axes would result in the "correct" transformation:  if we turn the coordinate system, the three numbers “revolve” on each other, get “mixed up” in each other, by precise laws as discussed by Feynman.

Still, we cannot say that the set of all possible rotations in $3D$ is a vector space, and consequently, our well-transforming three numbers are not the components of a vector representing a rotation. The reason is that in order to have a vector **we must say something about the meaning of the operations defined on the set of objects**. In particular, to make contact with the mathematical definition of vector space, we must define the multiplication by a scalar and the sum of two rotations. No problem emerges from the multiplication by a scalar. The sum of two rotations instead, is not the same as the usual parallelogram rule for two arrows. It can be easily seen by applying two successive $90^{\circ}$ rotations around two orthogonal directions, say around the $z$ and $x$ axis. The final result of applying before the $z$, and after the $x$ axis rotations is not the same if the order of the two rotations is inverted (some nice images can be found in the answers to this [question on Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2016937/why-is-the-product-of-two-rotation-matrices-not-commutative) ). This implies that the sum of two rotations, defined as the final rotation, is not commutative, and this implies the failure of associating a vector space to the $3D$ rotations. Actually, it is well known that only infinitesimal rotations can be associated with vectors.

In summary, the main claim in Feynman's lecture is correct: it is not enough to associate three real numbers to a physical quantity to have a vector. However, the reason is not what Feynman's said, but the fact that the mathematical definition of a vector space contains, as a fundamental ingredient, the association of combination rules to the set of elements, and such rules have some constraints. In particular, the sum must be commutative. Notice that the composition rules are at the core of the possibility of introducing the vector components and their transformation rules. Therefore they should be considered the most basic requirement to define what a vector is.

Comment: I like your answer the best but I think it still misses the fundamental difference between vectors and representations of vectors as linear combinations of elements of a basis of that vector space. Components only appear once we fix a basis and now we have the problem that there are many possible choices for the basis. A combination of coefficients without a choice of basis is still meaningless, isn't it? Of course at this point you might as well give a full course on linear algebra and vector spaces, which the OP will probably not appreciate.

Comment: @FlatterMann The difference between vectors and their representation through their component in a basis exists, but from the algebraic point of view, it is not that fundamental, due to the isomorphism existing between the two sets. Anyway, you hit the point: I had to stop before starting a full course on linear algebra :-)

Comment: I am not denying that in much more advanced maths, they would sometimes cover vectors with a definition that includes this extra "combination rules" or "constraints". However, most basic undergrad texts in maths on vector spaces are actually only covering linear spaces, and so the students would have completely missed this important distinction. Feynman most likely predated the popularisation of what you are talking about, so you should cut him some slack.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Certainly, I put Feynman's words in the context of the time they were expressed. I do not blame him The problem is that nowadays, some people think that everything in the Lectures remains the ultimate word.

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 That is rather unfortunate. After all, aren't we supposed to think that there would be progress? _looks around, despairs_

Answer (score 11):

Every mathematical object both is and is not a vector, depending on context.  To ask whether (3,5,9) is a "vector" is like asking whether Barack Obama is a "member".  He is in fact a member of some clubs and not of others. To meaningfully ask "is Barack Obama a member?", you have to have some particular club in mind.  To meaningfully ask whether (3,5,9) is a vector, you have to have some particular vector space in mind.

A (real) vector space is a collection of mathematical objects together with some rule for adding two vectors together and some rule for multiplying a scalar (that is, a real number) times a vector.  (There are also some axioms these operations must satisfy, which others have listed.)  When you have a vector space in mind, the elements of that vector space are called vectors.  When you don't have a vector space in mind, those same elements are not called vectors.

Example 1:  There is a vector space consisting of all triples of real numbers.  You can add two of these, and you can multiply by scalars, in the usual way.  When you have that vector space in mind, any triple of real numbers a vector, and nothing else is a vector.

Example 2:  There is a vector space consisting of all quadratic polynomials with real coefficients.  You can add two of these, and you can multiply by scalars, in the usual way.  When you have that vector space in mind, any quadratic polynomial with real coefficients is a vector, and nothing else is a vector.

Example 3 (this is bizarre one, but perfectly legitimate):  There is a vector space consisting of all triples of real numbers **except** for (0,0,0), along with the number 8.  You've decided to add these and to multiply by scalars according to the usual rules for triples, together with the rule that v+8=v for any vector v, and r x 8 = 8 for any scalar r.  When you have that vector space in mind, (3,7,1), (2,-1,0) and 8 are all vectors, but (0,0,0) is not a vector.

Example 4:  Just like example 4, but instead of the number 8, use the unit circle (not the various elements of the unit circle, but the unit circle itself).  With this vector space in mind, the unit circle is a vector.  With any of Examples 1,2,3 in mind, it is  not.

Finally: Take the example from @rob's answer.  He is talking about triples for which you have no good definition of addition.  (You could try adding two of these triples in the usual way, but you'd get a third triple that isn't one of the allowable triples).   If you have this collection of triples in mind, then you do not have any vector space in mind at all.  Then (768023, 44126, 295770) is not a vector (and neither is anything else).  But if you have example 1 in mind, then the same triple **is** a vector.

Comment: I think (but am not sure) that Feynman's argument also contains the following point: if V is a real vector space with dimension 3, then for every basis B of V, a triple of real numbers represents a vector in V; which means that each triple of real numbers corresponds to different vectors for different bases, and conversely each vector of V is represented by different triples under different bases; so that "vector = triple of real numbers" is not a good simplification, even when vectors are represented by triples of real numbers.

Comment: So, the reason that any three numbers don't form a vector is due to the fact that the vector space definitions need to be taken into consideration. Three arbitrary numbers won't necessarily form a vector if the vector space is defined as only consisting of a limited set of number combinations. Is that right?

Answer (score 10):

If you write down any three $\mathbb R$-numbers, then they constitute an element of the vector space $\mathbb R^3$. This is obviously true, which is leads to (understandable) confusion about what physicists mean when we say that not all sets of numbers constitute vectors.

What we mean is that if you consider three $\mathbb R$-valued quantities **which have their own transformation rules** and then compile them into a 3-tuple, then that list does not generally transform in the same way that an honest vector does.  I'll give you an example, in 2D for simplicity.

Let $\mathbf u = (1,0)$ and $\mathbf v = (2,1)$ be elements of $\mathbb R^2$.  Under the action of a rotation matrix $R_\theta$, we have

$$\mathbf u \mapsto \mathbf u' = R_\theta \mathbf u = \pmatrix{\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta}\pmatrix{1\\0} = \pmatrix{\cos\theta\\\sin\theta}$$
$$\mathbf v \mapsto \mathbf v' = R_\theta\mathbf v = \pmatrix{2\cos\theta -\sin\theta\\ 2\sin\theta + \cos\theta}$$

More generally, a vector $\mathbf w$ is sent to $\mathbf w' = R_\theta\mathbf w$ which has components $w'^i = (R_{\theta})^i_{\ \ j} w^j$.

---

Now I will define a list $\mathbf x = \big(\Vert \mathbf u \Vert , \mathbf u \cdot \mathbf v\big) = (1,2)$. Its components are $\mathbb R$-valued, but they are defined in terms of quantities which already have their own prescribed transformation behaviors. That is, under the action of the rotation we would have that

$$\mathbf x \mapsto \mathbf x' = \big(\Vert \mathbf u' \Vert , \mathbf u' \cdot \mathbf v'\big) = (1,2)$$

However, it's easy to see that because the norm and dot product are invariant under rotations, $\mathbf x' = \mathbf x$.  If $\mathbf x$ were a vector, then we would have that
$$\mathbf x' = R_\theta \mathbf x = \pmatrix{\cos\theta - 2 \sin\theta\\ \sin\theta + 2\cos\theta} \neq \mathbf x$$

---

So to summarize, given a vector space $V\simeq \mathbb R^n$, vectors transform in a particular way under the action of a linear transformation $T$. Any arbitrary list of $n$ $\mathbb R$-numbers defines a vector (in some basis, at least). However, not any arbitrary list of $n$ $\mathbb R$-valued *quantities* - which have their own independent existences - transforms in the same way.

Answer (score 6):

For a mathematician, a vector is a member of a vector space. A vector space is a set of vectors that form a group under $+$. Multiplication by any real (or complex) number gives another vector in the space.

You have to define the set and the operations to make a vector space. You can't define a single vector in isolation. Unless you are defining a trivial vector space containing only the vector $\vec 0$.

There are many ways to define a set and two operations that do not make a vector space. Take a finite set. Take a + operation where $\vec x + \vec y$ always adds to the same vector.

Perhaps you are thinking that given any three numbers, you can always define a vector space that holds them. Perhaps.

Take something off the wall like the x coordinate of position and the y and z coordinates of velocity. You can make a vector space out of this. Take addition to add coordinates as usual. Take multiplication to multiply each coordinate as usual. It is indeed a vector space.

---

Physicists have one more requirement. It must transform correctly when you change the basis.

The coordinates must be physically meaningful. And when you change the basis by taking a linear combination of them, they must still be physically meaningful.

In practice, this means they must all be the same kind of quantity. E.G. All must be distance, or all must be velocity.

So a phase space from thermodynamics is a real example of a mathematical vector space that is not a physics vector space. For a system with $n$ atoms, it is a $6n$ dimensional space. It has the $3$ spatial coordinates of each particle, and the $3$ momentum coordinates. A single very complex point represents the position and momentum of every atom.

Physicists use such a space, but not as a vector space. As the system evolves in time, they track the state of the system by the position of the point in the space. They never add two points together, or multiply the point by a number. They certainly never change the basis to see the system from the point of view of another inertial frame of reference.

Another instructive example is space time. This combines $3$ spatial coordinates and $1$ time coordinate into a single $4$D vector space. In this space, you do make linear combinations out of space and time. They are physically meaningful. They are needed to correctly represent the system as seen from another inertial frame of reference. This works because space and time are much more alike than you would guess from everyday experience.

One such similarity is the failure of simultaneity. Alice stands by the side of the road, while Bob drives by. At $t_0$, they are both in the same place. At $t_1$, Alice says she is in the same place as before, but Bob has moved. Bob disagrees. He is still in the place he was at. Nobody is surprised by this disagreement.

They are surprised by the equivalent disagreement about time intervals. Alice$_1$ and Alice$_2$ are at opposite ends of a train station. Bob$_1$ and Bob$_2$ ride by in the caboose and engine of a train. The Bobs have synchronized their watches. They agree that Bob$_1$ passes Alice$_1$ at the same time that Bob$_2$ passes Alice$_2$. The Alices have also synchronized their watches. They say that when Bob$_1$ passes Alice$_1$, Bob$_2$ has not yet reached Alice$_2$. Bob$_1$ passes Alice$_1$ at a later time.

Comment: There is a good reason why the 6N dimensional phase space is not usually treated as a vector space. In general, it isn't, due to the nature of the generalized coordinates used in the Hamiltonian formalisms.

Comment: *Physicists have one more requirement. It must transform correctly when you change the basis.* Actually, this is not an additional requirement. It is a consequence of the vector space axioms.

Answer (score 5):

Every triple of (real) numbers is an element of the vector space $\mathbb{R}^3$ and hence by definition a vector as you have already
found out.

In physics we often deal with the euclidean space $E$ (the Riemannian manifold of all points in 3D-space). We describe this space by picking an orthogonal coordinate system on $E$, that is an isometry $i: E \to \mathbb{R}^3$. Now **what Feynman really means is that the numbers produced by $i$ and the numbers produced by any other orthogonal coordinate system on $E$ must be related to each other in a specific way**.
I will describe this relation below:

### Coordinate isomorphism and change of basis

First of there is a natural isometry between $E$ and the tangent space of $E$ at any point $o$, where a point $p\in E$ corresponds to the vector pointing from $o$ to $p$. So we get a full description of $E$ by considering only the tangent space of $E$ for a point $o \in E$ (the origin).

We choose an origin $o$ and a basis $A= (a_1, a_2 ,a_3)$ of the tangent space $T_o E$ of $E$ at $o$ and then we have an isomorphism (an invertible linear map)
\begin{align}
J: E &\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^3 \\
\alpha_1 a_1 + \alpha_2 a_2 + \alpha_3 a_3 &\longmapsto \begin{pmatrix} \alpha_1 \\ \alpha_2 \\ \alpha_3 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
that sends an euclidean vector to its components with respect to the basis $A$.
Now if we take a different basis $B =(b_1, b_2, b_3)$ of the tangent space to $o$ of $E$, then we obtain another isomorphism $I: E \to \mathbb{R}^3 $ of the same kind.
We can ask the question what the relation between the components of a vector $v \in E$ with respect to $A$ and $B$ is.
We can do this as follows:
For $i \in \{1,2,3\}$ we have that $b_i = \sum_{j=1}^{3} c_{ji}a_j$ for some coefficients $c_{ji} \in \mathbb{R}$ since $A$ is a basis.
We can form a matrix $C=(c_{ji})_{j,i} \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$ from these coefficients.

Let $v = \sum_{j=1}^3 \alpha_j a_j \in E$ and also $v =\sum_{i=1}^3 \beta_i b_i $ . Then we have
$$v = \sum_{i=1}^3 \beta_i b_i = 
\sum_{i=1}^3 \sum_{j=1}^3 \beta_i c_{ji} a_j $$
and therefore since the coordinates are unique we have using matrix multiplication
$$\begin{pmatrix} \alpha_1 \\ \alpha_2 \\ \alpha_3 \end{pmatrix} = C \cdot \begin{pmatrix} \beta_1 \\ \beta_2 \\ \beta_3 \end{pmatrix} .$$
And so we found the relationship between the old coordinates and the new ones.

Now in the case of euclidean space $E$, we are only interested in the case where $A$ and $B$ are both an orthonormal basis so that $J$ and $I$ are isometric isomorphisms when $\mathbb{R}^3$ carries the usual scalar product. This further restricts $C$ to be a member of the orthognal group $O(3)$. Note that we can also choose different origins $o$ and look at how the coordinate system transforms in that case.

Answer (score 5):

> I can't imagine any 3 numbers that when combined to form a vector, wouldn't satisfy these axioms

I assume that when you say "combined to form a vector" you actually mean "combined to form a [tuple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple)" (i.e. an ordered list) - otherwise you would be asking "are there vectors which are not vectors". So your question becomes "are there tuples which are not vectors". And the answer is definitely yes.

For example, suppose we define the sum of two 3-tuples $A = (a_1,a_2,a_3)$ and $B = (b_1,b_2,b_3)$ as $A+B = (\max(a_1,b_1), \max(a_2,b_2), \max(a_3,b_3))$. and the multiplication of $A$ by a scalar $t$ as $tA = (a_1, ta_2, t^2a_3)$. Then we have made some sort of algebraic space from our collection of 3-tuples, but it is certainly not a vector space.

A vector is not an ordered list of numbers. It is a mathematical object that can be added to other vectors and multiplied by scalars in a way that conforms with the axioms of a vector space. A vector may be *represented* by an ordered list of numbers, which are its co-ordinates relative to a given co-ordinates system. And once we introduce the co-ordinate representation then we can define vector addition and multiplication in terms of operations on these co-ordinates. It is a mistake to identify a vector with its co-ordinate representation because (a) a vector has many different co-ordinate representations, depending on the chosen co-ordinates system and (b) just being handed a tuple of numbers does not guarantee that that tuple is part of a vector space, as the example above shows.

Answer (score 3):

> Of course it is generally not true that any three numbers form a vector
>
> In order for it to be a vector, not only must there be three numbers, but these must be associated with a coordinate system in such a way that if we turn the coordinate system, the three numbers “revolve” on each other, get “mixed up” in each other, by the precise laws we have already described.

He is saying that a vector in a $3$-dim. vector space can be identified with a function that assigns three numbers to each basis (coordinate system) and that satisfies a certain transformation rule. Here is how to put this into math language:

Let $V$ be an $n$-dim. $F$-vector space. A basis corresponds to a vector space isomorphism $B\in L(V,F^n)$. Let $A\subset L(V,F^n)$ be the set of all bases and
$$W:=\{f:A\to F^n:\forall B,\tilde B\in A:f(\tilde B)=\tilde B B^{-1}f(B)\}$$
then we can define a bijection
$$\Phi:V\to W$$
by setting
$$\forall v\in V:\forall B\in A:\Phi(v)(B)=B(v).$$

Answer (score 2):

Consider the list
\begin{align}
(N_f,\, N_c,\, N_s) = (10, 1, 0)
\end{align}
where $N_f$ is the number of fingers on my hands, $N_c$ is the number of cats on my bed, and $N_s$ is the number of shoes on my feet. These numbers don't change under any Euclidean coordinate transformation, so this list of numbers is not a Euclidean vector.

Comment: Of course these change under coordinate transformations.  Let P be the number of figures on your hand minus the number of cats on your bed, Q the number of cats on your bed minus the number of shoes on your feet, and R twice the number of shoes on your feet.  Then your triple transforms in the new coordinates to (P=9,Q=1,R=0).

Comment: @WillO I've edited my answer to conform to your pedantry.

Comment: d_b:  The transformation here is an element of SO(3).  If that doesn't count as euclidean, I can't imagine what does.  And for novices struggling to understand basic concepts, pedantry is very often exactly what's needed.

Comment: @WillO I don't see how that can be true... It's not an orthogonal transformation. Anyway, that's beside the point. Of course you can take any list of three numbers, treat it as an element of $\mathbf{R}^3$, and look at transformations on that space. The point is that the relevant transformations act on physical space, not some abstract vector space, and I'm sure you know exactly what Feynman means in the quoted passage. I'm not sure what point you're trying to make, and if you have substantive feedback I'm happy to try to incorporate it in my answer, but, respectfully, your comment reads...

Comment: ... as semantic nitpicking.

Comment: You are right of course that I gave a non-orthogonal example and you are also right that an orthogonal example would have been much better.   Beyond that, I honestly have no idea what you (and Feynman) are talking about.  But I am quite sure that students at an early stage tend to need a lot of what you call semantic nitpicking, and are only going to be further confused if you give them answers that are flat-out wrong but then claim that the wrongness somehow doesn't count for some vaguely worded reason.

Comment: Like @WillO, I also honestly never understood the "physics" definition of vector. The coordinates of any vector transform in a certain way because that's how the math works out when you work it out. I can't imagine a vector whose coordinates transform in a "wrong" way. I've tried but I just don't get it.

Answer (score 2):

**The problem is not wether three *numbers* form a vector; the issue is whether three *variables* form a vector.** Calling a variable "a number" is likely a simplification and your question exposes a shortcoming of that simplification.

There's nothing intrinsecally vector-like or vector-unlike in the values $(1,10,\pi)$ that make them "a vector" or not. It depends on what those numbers represent in your model of... something.

If the three numbers are, say, geometrical coordinates, then the mathematical structure of a vector space (scalar multiplication, addition etc.) will be meaningful in how your model describes space: vector addition describes a traslation, scalar multiplication an enlargement/reduction and several geometrical transformation can be expressed in the language of linear algebra.

If you pick unrelated variables (i.e. temperature, userID, number of students enrolled in physycs 101) or variables that are related but for which the vector space operations do not make sense (such as temperature, humidity and air pressure) then you have what most people would call "not-a-vector" because even if you *could* do linear algebra with those numbers, those operations do not correspond to anything meaningful about what those numbers are describing, so they are not "a vector" in that sense.